# I need a REGEX that can cover any hyphen, any paranthesis, forward slashes, paranthesis, etc

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract data from a list of files, and I want to use regex to be able to extract account names from the tables in these files. I've been trying to match and I have some luck, but I need a more robust regex, to be able to extract full account names.

I've tested some of the account names that give the most trouble and this is how far I've gotten. I'm able to match up until "-" in some cases, which is great. Also, not sure why "United Money Mgmt Corp" is returning as only "United Money Mgmt". Not too great w/ Regex, so I need help.

```
<re.Match object; span=(0,22), match='20/36 Advert Inc. -'
<re.Match object; span=(0,14), match='COOLIDGE LLC -'
<re.Match object; span=(0,20), match='YANG STREET CAPITAL '
<re.Match object; span=(0,20), match='United Money Mgmt '
<re.Match object; span=(0,13), match='JQUM (Chex '
<re.Match object; span=(0,5), match='AXEY '
<re.Match object; span=(0,9), match='RIG /COV'
```

This is the regex I'm using:

```
company_regex = re.compile(r'^[\w\d\s]+(?:[-/\.\s()]+[\w\d\s.-]+)?\s+')
```

For reference, these are the full names I'm trying to extract:

```
company_1= "20/36 Advert Inc. -New York"
company_2= "COOLIDGE LLC - CHARLOTTE"
company_3= "YANG STREET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"
company_4= "United Money Mgmt Corp"
company_5= "JQUM (Chex Stanley)"
company_6= "AXEY (Mitsu+XG+JNL)"
company_7= "RIG /Cov Credit"
```

The names are embedded across multiple PDFs that follow this format. I'm just trying to build a regex that would cover these "account names" since they seem to be wilder:

| Account | Allocation |
| --- | --- |
| 20/36 Advert Inc. - New York | 4.00k |
| COOLIDGE LLC - CHARLOTTE | 3.3m |
| United Money Mgmt Corp | 7.5m |
| JQUM (Chex Stanley) | $3.8 |
| AXEY (Mitsu+XG+JNL) | $75.8k |
| RIG /Cov Credit | 100.0k |

Comment: Please provide: (a) Example rows of input text (b) The actual program you have created so far and (c) Exactly what you want the output to be. Otherwise you will be stuck here with people expected to read your mind.

Comment: Without seeing what these names are embedded in, it's hard to know what the regexp is supposed to exclude.

Comment: What is the "span" that we're supposed to ignore?

Comment: This is likely to be beyond the capabilities of a regular expression. Company names are much too flexible to be matched by any simple pattern.

Comment: So are you asking to match the subset of the larger names ?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
r'^((?:[\d\/]+)?[\w\d\s\.]+)(?:\s+[\-\/\.\s()]+)?'
```

I obtained result:

```
20/36 Advert Inc. 
COOLIDGE LLC
YANG STREET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT
United Money Mgmt Corp
JQUM
AXEY
RIG
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Almost! I need it to include "-" so that for example it returns the whole string "20/36 Advert Inc. - New York". I also need it to include '+' and ')' so that for example the whole account names " JQUM (Chex Stanley) " and AXEY (Mitsu+XG+JNL) are returned and not just "JQUM (Chex " and "AXEY " which are incomplete matches.

Comment: You need to remove "()" from the third square brackets and add "()+" to the second... As you wish: https://regex101.com/r/4ng6CK/2 and do on - you can try yourself :)

Comment: As before (yesterday) there seemed to be clear criteria for distinguishing the desired parts of the names. There was a good result as in the answer above. With "()+" there is also a chance for quite clear criteria. But if you want " - New York" in the result, then it will also be " - CHARLOTTE" too - because why not? (By capital letters? Try it  https://regex101.com/r/4ng6CK/3 ) Criteria increasingly unclear. As a result - almost everything. And also like @Barmar "This is likely to be beyond the capabilities of a regular expression. Company names are much too flexible". Please consider it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simpler ways to extract a select region of interest is using `PDFtotext` where we can use batches of profiles for different situations.

So as an example take this page as a PDF then we can target individual columns or pairs of columns and even alter their means of storage such as to add characters to build a CSV or line indexed file. Even use some Regex, and in this case we could do a file compare to spot that the first list has 7 companies but the second list only has 6 :-)

[image]

no point in posting the console code (simply type `pdftotext -h`), but built as a bash / cmd / bat script or "shelled" from Adder, Boa, Conda, or other snake like programming language, is easy.